# How to check for mcrypt existence at the start of moodle installation

Tags: php, moodle

I am new to `moodle`. Would really appericiate if you people can help me out here.

I am creating a repository plugin in moodle for which I need that `mcrypt` has to be installed before moodle get installed on the machine. I was wondering if any of you can tell me how I can I stop moodle installation if mcrypt is not installed, as I don't want to temper core files of moodle.

Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the extension loaded method

```
<?php
if (!extension_loaded('mcrypt')) {
    // do something if you don't have mcrypt
}

// run rest of script as normal with mcrypt installed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I don't want to change my core files so plz guide me how to put an extra file when installing the moodle.

Comment: I can't see how you would prevent `moodle` itself from being installed unless you either change the core files or build some kind of pre-installer that runs your checks then triggers the moodle installer if they pass